# JavaScript library to create div-style window within page

Tags: .net, javascript, dhtml

Im trying to find out a good JavaScript library that can create a nice "inner-window" popup within a page on my site.

I would like to not have to worry about screen positioning (i.e. dont have to calcuate if the size of the window will be off screen, etc...), but just make a new pop-up that has content in it.

I'll be using .NET 3.5 ASP.NET (maybe MVC, havent started yet), I know JQuery has great support, but from what I have seen, it doesnt have this type of widget feature.

Please note, I do not want to use "frames" in any way, shape, or form! But rather the floating div style approach (or similar).

Thanks heaps!
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Floating containers, panels and dialogs:**

For dialog boxes and windows, perhaps a [**YUI module**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/module/) would be a **good solution**.

**Modal Boxes**

If you **aren't a javascript programmer**, and you're interested in a more-elaborate modal box, there are jQuery **plugins** [**offering**](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) the [**modal lightbox effect**](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).

**Sidenote:** There are many libraries offering this kind of functionality, but if the box itself is the only piece you need, keep in consideration that **some libraries will include many things you aren't using**.  If you're careful to use only the packages you need, you can keep your page nice and lean.

**Sidenote:** If you're fairly well-versed with javascript, or wish to become so, remember that you can always *write your own*.  It's common for people in the javascript world to turn straight to libraries.  Libraries are an important part of the modern javascript landscape, but sometimes they become a crutch for developers.  Writing a few front-end pieces yourself is a great way to dive into front-end development.

Comment: I have certianly written a lot of Javascript libraries in the past, its fine and I can do it, its just that these days with so many abstraction libraries, I thought, for cross-browser's sake, and all the other things I keep re-inventing, I would look at a 3rd party one.

Comment: Absolutely. If those are your concerns, I'd go with YUI. The entire YUI library is massive, but if you just include the pieces you need, it can be much smaller. It's well-architected, and needless to say, the YUI team is on top of the browser game.

Answer (score 1):

I have used one called [iBox](http://www.ibegin.com/labs/ibox/) and it has worked well.

If you are already using jQuery then you might want to check out these [two](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) [options](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Dialog widget for JQuery?

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Demo at the bottom. Don't worry about the ugly (IMHO) colours, they can be styled easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help so far, I have just taken a look at light box, and although very nice, I was hoping for a non-page-blocking library, these all seem to (at a first glace) grey-out the rest of the page, I was hoping for less of this, and more just an inline content based window that does not block the rest of the page.

Comment: See my note on YUI modules.. They're a clean and easy solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just finished looking at this, looks nice. I think I will give it a go to start with. Although I will just wait a few more minutes before making it as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Check [Control.Window](http://livepipe.net/control/window) it's based on Prototype.