# How to display "window" inside website with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript library to create div-style window within page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199872/javascript-library-to-create-div-style-window-within-page)

I would like to display "above" standard content of my website a "window" with some content. I don't mean to open a new browser window. I mean to make some kind of div that floats above rest of the page. It needs to be move'able and able to interact with rest of the website with JS (so no IFRAMEs) and it should have also a icon to close in right up corner like Windows window. i've seen such thing in some online SAAS systems. Do you know any library in JS that has something like this? I need only this so i don't want any library-cows that can do everything else also. Only the window. And it should be also compatible with IE9, Chrome latest and FF latest.

I try to find it for some time now. Do you know such solution?

Comment: See [JavaScript library to create div-style window within page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199872/javascript-library-to-create-div-style-window-within-page).

Comment: I'm sure others will supply answers with libraries and scripts that do this, as it's quite common. Personally, I would dare to suggest dynamically adjusting the content and layout of the page to fit the new content in place - floating things are just a hangover from desktop days, and lock the user into a dialog mode. Modes (vim aside) are generally a bad usability choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like a dialog inside the page? You can find one in JQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/